# Natural deduction proof - problem with existential elimination

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have problems with the following proof:
$$
\forall x \exists y (Rxy \land Py), \forall x \neg Rxx \vdash \neg \forall x \forall y (Px \implies (Py \implies x=y))
$$
The problem is with the application of the existential elimination rule - no matter what, there are other undischarged assumptions which prevent me from applying the rule.

Edit: The empty structure is not a valid domain

Comment: Actually it can't be deduced without a further existential premise, as the empty structure satisfies the left hand side, but not the right hand side.

Comment: In our system (at university) we excluded the empty structure as a valid domain (which I should have added, sorry)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what system you are using, but here is a proof in Fitch:

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks! It seems so obvious once you spell it out :( Would you have any tips on these kind of proofs, where it's important how you instantiate the variables?

Comment: @JPR Well, given that the conclusion was a negation, doing a proof by contradiction seemed pretty obvious, and when you have a mix of quantifiers, you always want to instantiate the existentials as soon as possible ... so, I instantiated the universal with $a$ to be able to instantiate the existential with $b$, and since it was clear I wasn't going to get the contradiction with $a$ (since you can just deny that $a$ has property $P$), I figured I'd just instantiate that same universal with $b$, and get the existential with $c$ ... and the rest was trivial from that point on.